# Fragment null object reference

Tags: java, android

So,im trying to call some methods of an extended fragment class into mainActivity and somehow i cant get the variable to reference the actual fragment.

It says im referencing a null object when im calling the frag.method() line.
Is it because of wrong id in findFragmentByid() inside of the onCreate() in mainActivity?

Ive tried using the id of the linear and constraint layout ('yes' and 'paint'),still get the error.

**Main activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ViewGroup.LayoutParams params;
    private Path path=new Path();
    private Paint brush = new Paint();
    private PaintView paintView;
    FirstFragment frag=new FirstFragment();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        frag = (FirstFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.paint);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        toolbar.setMinimumWidth(20);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        switch  (id){
            case R.id.eraser:
                frag.eraser();
                return true;
            case R.id.brush:
               frag.brush();
                return true;
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**FirstFragment**

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    public FirstFragment() {}
    private PaintView paintView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState

    ) {
        View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first,container,false);

        LinearLayout Rl= (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.paint);
        paintView=new PaintView(getActivity());
        Rl.addView(paintView);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        paintView.brush();
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
/*
        view.findViewById(R.id.button_first).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(FirstFragment.this)
                        .navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment);
            }
        });
        */
    }
    public void eraser()
    {
        paintView.eraser();
    }
    public void brush(){
        paintView.brush();
    }

}
```

**first_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/yes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/paint"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Error**

```
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 29743
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.myapplication.FirstFragment.eraser()' on a null object reference
            at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:50)
            at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:4137)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:436)
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:196)
            at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:109)
            at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:109)
            at androidx.appcompat.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:64)
            at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:204)
            at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:781)
            at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:840)
            at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
            at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:991)
            at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:981)
            at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:625)
            at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:151)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
            at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
            at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
   29743-29743/com.example.myapplication I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 29743 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Simple logical error: A fragment isn't created until the activation creation is complete. Activity creation isn't completed in `onCreate`. Hence, you cannot reference a fragment inside onCreate without a UI callback.

Comment: Right so where should i reference that fragment?Or how?How is it logical if someone didnt even know how fragments are created?
How is your comment even helping...

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal 
Well you really didnt know what you were talking about,the problem was caused by the fact there was no fragment existing,not because i referenced it at the wrong time,thank you for misleading me.You should refrain from talking about things you didnt even bother to read(my code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp,the problem was caused by the fact that there was no fragment in the respective layout since the layout(yes,paint) was INSIDE the fragment i was trying to call,so basically id mismatch.Stupid me.